# Нахождение производной

Tags: c++, математика

Есть задача:
 Написать программу, которая реализует подбор значений с целью поиска максимального значения второй производной. Требуемое значение может быть найдено путем проверки промежуточных значений функции (или первой / второй производной). Следует использовать указатель на функцию, для которого определить typedef. Исходный код должен быть разделен на две единицы трансляции. Первая единица трансляции будет представлена ​​заголовочным файлом и файлом реализации. Определение typedef, а также прототип функции поиска нужного значения, должны быть расположены в заголовочном файле. Определение этой функции следует осуществить в файле реализации. Функция для проверки работоспособности программы, а также функция main (), должны быть расположены в другой единице трансляции. 

 Функция для тестирования может быть произвольной.

 Не долго раздумывая, взял y = x^2

```
// file main.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "derivative.h"
using namespace std;
double parabola(double x) {
    return pow(x, 2);
}
void main() {
    printf("%.8f\n", firstDerivative(parabola, 2));
}



// file derivative.h
#pragma once
#ifndef DERIVATIVE_H
#define DERIVATIVE_H
typedef double(*parabolaPointer)(double);
double firstDerivative(parabolaPointer f, double);
#endif



// file derivative.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "derivative.h"
#pragma once
double firstDerivative(parabolaPointer f, double x, double deltaX = 0.0000001) {
    return (f(x + deltaX) - f(x)) / deltaX;
}
```

Производную считаю по формуле y'(x) = (y(x + Δx) - y(x)) / Δx

 Если я вместо х, подставляю 2, то считает оно правильно. Выводит 4.0000009

 Обгуглив все, что можно на тему как найти вторую производную, я ничего не нашел. Разве что на cyberforum.ru было что-то связанное с производными высших порядков.

```
double Numerator = (f(x + deltaX) - f(x0 + deltaX)) / ((x + deltaX) - (x0 + deltaX)) - (f(x) - f(x0)) / (x - x0);
double secondDerivative = Numerator / deltaX;
```

Только что-то считает оно как-то неправильно. 
Спросив у лектора помощи, он сказал, не имеет права помогать с заданиями. Добавил только, что в этом задании мне, для начала, нужно найти формулу нахождения второй производной, потом найти несколько производных на неком интервале и занести их в вектор. В цикле пройтись по вектору и найти максимальное значение. С этим я справлюсь, мой вопрос, кто-нибудь может, пожалуйста, помочь с нахождением второй производной либо хотя бы есть какая-то формула?

Comment: вторая производная - это производная первой производной

Comment: я знаю, как это реализовать с помощью кода?

Comment: Парабола не очень подходит, вторая производная будет константа

Comment: "Не долго раздумывая, взял y = x^2". "Недолго раздумывая" - ключевые слова. Задача годится для ф-ций, имеющих третью производную. Найдите ее в виде функции по @igor. Приравняйте нулю, и, затем ищите корень по Ньютону. Получится изящно.

Comment: Ну, можно взять y = sinx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double secondDerivative(parabolaPointer f, double x, double deltaX = 0.0000001) {
  double v1 = firstDerivative(f, x, deltaX);
  double v2 = firstDerivative(f, x + deltaX, deltaX);
  return (v2 - v1) / deltaX;
}
```

Не называйте "`parabolaPointer`" то, что является указателем на общую функцию с параметром `double`, возвращающую `double`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я такого метода, честно, нигде не находил.

Comment: @Overthesanity - "такого метода не находил" - Мой. Дарю! :)